# JsPDF Inaccurately Displays Tables

Tags: angularjs, jspdf, html2canvas

I'm attempting to use JsPDF and HTML2Canvas to create a downloadable PDF file. I'm using AngularJs. The HTML content contains several long tables that are sometimes 3-4x the width of the PDF. Although the PDF ends up close to perfect, I've run into several defects:

- Table columns occasionally don't display their respective values in the PDF (partial or no data)
- If a date field is not provided, the table in the PDF defaults to 12/31/9999
- A single row table shifts all its values left by one. As a result, there is no record/ID and the last column value is undefined.
- I tried messing around with margins and content width. Unfortunately, only margin.top/left have any effect.

This is the code I've used:

```
$scope.savePdfSample = function(value) {

            html2canvas(document.body,{
                onrendered:function(canvas){
                    var doc = new jsPDF('l', 'pt', 'letter'),
                        source = $("#template_invoice")[0], //not sure what this does

                   margins = {
                        top: 40,
                        bottom: 40,
                        left: 40,
                        right:40,
                        width: 1000,
                    };

                    doc.fromHTML(
                        $("#ccsReport1").html(),
                        margins.left,
                        margins.top,
                        {
                            'width': margins.width,
                        },
                        function(dispose) {
                            doc.save('CCS Case Details.pdf');
                        },
                        margins
                    );
                }
            });
        };
```

I've tried messing around with the jspdf.debug.js file, but I haven't found a solution yet. I'd appreciate anyone pointing me in the right direction. Thank you.